# Pygame game attempt not working and i can't figure out why

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to make this game called 4 in a row or something, I'm quite new to pygame and python in general so yeah...
It says it crashes because get closest isn't getting the vpos value but I did set it as the y array...

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([620, 520])
running = True
Emptygray = (220,220,220)
Bordergray = (105, 105, 105)
y = []
x = []
m = 0
n = 0
urgo = True
for i in range(0,30): 
    x.append(0) 
    y.append(0)
    m = 0
    n = 0
def getclosest(mousey, vpos):
    r = 0
    for i in range(0,5):
        s = abs(mousey[1] - vpos[i])
        if r < s: r = i
    return r

print(len(x))
while running:
    screen.fill((202, 164, 114))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    for i in range(0,6):
        for j in range(0,5):
            a = 60
            b = 60
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, Bordergray, ( a + 100 * i, b + 100 * j), 47)
            if n < 30: x[n] = [a + 100 * i]
            if n <= 30: n += 1
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, Emptygray, ( a + 100 * i, b + 100 * j), 44)
            if m < 30: y[m] = [b + 100 * j]
            if m <= 30: m += 1
    if urgo:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                print(mousey = getclosest(pygame.mouse.get_pos()), vpos = y[0:4])
    pygame.display.flip()
    #print ("x:", x)
    #print ("y:", y)
```

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
getclosest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vpos'
  File "C:\Users\NOEL\Desktop\Folders\Python\Game\3.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(mousey = getclosest(pygame.mouse.get_pos()), vpos = y[0:4])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(mousey = getclosest(pygame.mouse.get_pos()), vpos = y[0:4])
```

should be

```
print(mousey = getclosest(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), vpos = y[0:4]))
```

Comment: We all make them :)